# Range methods for DoubleStream and LongStream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Why don't **DoubleStream** or **LongStream** have similar methods as these ones (which exist in IntStream):

```
public static IntStream range(int startInclusive, int endExclusive);
public static IntStream rangeClosed(int startInclusive, int endInclusive);
```

Is there any particular reason?

Comment: yes there is a very valuable reason. How many double can you fit in the range 1.0 to 2.0 ?

Comment: Because double ranges are not discrete ranges. They represent a non-enumerable set.

Comment: Isn't long discrete?

Comment: `LongStream` does have `range` and `rangeClosed`.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/LongStream.html#range-long-long-

Comment: You could mimic `range()` by combining `iterate()` and `takeWhile()` operations. Are you interested in sample (in answer), or will you be able to infer how it works on your own?

Comment: I would takeWhile() but I'm able to infer it :) thanks.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov this is for Java 8, takeWhile is 9.

Comment: @fidudidu, then you'll need to manually count steps in range and use `limit()`, I think.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov you surely do not want to pay the price of `iterate`, `takeWhile`, and/or `limit` for a simple counting loop. There’s a [clean and efficient alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57958224/range-methods-for-doublestream-and-longstream#comment102330221_57958306).

Comment: @Holger, it depends. If it really is a counting loop, then sure. But if range boundaries are user-defined, it's not quite as simple, becuse that method requires you to know the number of steps upfront. Though `IntStream::range` is better than `limit()`, that's for sure.

Comment: if the precision step is passed to the range method it would work for a double stream. That would make the double precision to become discrete and the problem of unlimited numbers wouldn't be a problem. (even though the double precision is limited to each machine's floating point limit)

Comment: @fidudidu, it would work, but not quite at all times, because certain decimal numbers aren't expressable via IEEE 754 binary64 (the `double`). For example, `0.34 + 0.01` is not quite `0.35` in java (test for yourself).

Comment: …or just consider why `for(double d = 0; d < 1; d += 0.1) { }` does eleven iterations instead of ten.

Comment: @Holger Yes, exactly. For other readers, contrast this to `for(double d = 1; d < 2; d += 0.1) { }` which does **ten** iterations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, `LongStream` does have `range()` methods.

`DoubleStream` probably doesn't have `range()` methods because mathematically there are infinite real numbers within any range of 2 `double` numbers, but only a finite subset of them can be represented with the `double` type.

Therefore, it's not clear what you want to get when you ask for a `DoubleStream` in the range of `-1.0` to `1.0`, for example.

Comment: Ok looks reasonable. Thanks.

Comment: Well, the computer’s `double` range is finite, but iterating over all values is rarely what the programmer intended. On the other hand, `IntStream.range(0, 10).asDoubleStream()` or `IntStream.range(0, 10).mapToDouble(i -> i*0.1)` do already work and it’s obvious to the reader, what these expressions will do.

Comment: A not-so-rare task is also to create a sequence of values like `0.0, 0.1, 0.2, ... , 1.0`, and one **could** consider some `range(min, max, stepSize)` method for this. But due to the limited precision of `double`, this has many caveats. It's probably good to keep this can of worms closed.

Comment: @Marco13 This is **exactly** why we didn't include `DoubleStream.range`. Do callers want values derived from increments added to the base value, or do they want values at equal intervals? We felt it would be better for callers to derive values explicitly from (say) an `IntStream` as Holger mentioned above.

Comment: @StuartMarks  That modest ambiguity did not stop `numpy` to have `linspace` : which is a _very_ popular method